# Apply CAGradientLayer to layer.borderColor

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement a underlined `UITextField` with a gradient. Therefore I created a extension with a function `underlined()`.

To get a gradient, I created a `CAGradientLayer` and made these customizations:

```
func underlined(){
        let color = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        let sndColor = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 178/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [color, sndColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        gradient.borderWidth = width

        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

A underline is being displayed, but it solely solid black - I've tried to change the colors, but it remains black (Issue outdated - see edit).

Does anybody see the issue?

**Edit:**
Adding `gradient.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor` let me change the color of the line - but how can I apply the gradient on the border color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the below line from your code:

```
gradient.borderWidth = width
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Your code was not working because, the `borderWidth` is covering whole of the gradient frame.Try setting the `borderColor`, then you'll see the difference.

```
gradient.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was about to become desperate.